# question regarding scaling for k-means clustering

Tags: distance

is it correct to say this?

we need to scale every numeric variable because if we don't, a variable with a large range of variance will dominate. So, one way to judge a variable with a large range of variance is to look at if the difference of min and max values is large.

can you please verify this? thx